# Can we use LayoutInflater jump to other activity?

Tags: android, layout-inflater

I know the `LayoutInflater` can load View dynamically.Can I jump to other View with  `LayoutInflater`?
I have write some code,but it doesn't work.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_viewpager);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                LayoutInflater lf = (LayoutInflater) VierPagerTestActivity.this
                        .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                LinearLayout linear = (LinearLayout)lf.inflate(R.layout.view_item, null);
            }
        });
```

Comment: What do you mean "jump" ?

Comment: I am not understand your question

Comment: I would suggest you to use another activity for this, or use Fragments.

Comment: Just go to other Activity

Answer (score 1):

Tricks:

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            LayoutInflater lf = (LayoutInflater) VierPagerTestActivity.this
                    .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            LinearLayout linear = (LinearLayout)lf.inflate(R.layout.view_item, null);
            setContentView(linear);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you are trying to get reference to layout.
For that you should call

```
setContentView(R.layout.view_item);
findViewById(R.id.viewId);
```

Method `findViewById` gets reference to view inside content view. In this case you should set id `@+id/viewId` for the view you want to get.